# How to get editable table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently i tried using editable table but when i edit a column then the whole table structure is getting effected,i showed it as a screen shot.

Initially,

[image]

When i tried editing,
[image]

My html,

```
  <div class="widget-body">
        <table class="table table-hover">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th class="hidden-xs-down">#</th>
                <th> <a (click)='getstudents(1)'>Account Name</a></th>
                <th class="hidden-xs-down"> <a (click)='getstudents(1)'>Phone</a></th>
                <th class="hidden-xs-down"> <a (click)='getstudents(1)'>Account Name ALias</a></th>
                 <th></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor = 'let student of students'>
                 <td class="hidden-xs-down">{{id}}</td>
                 <td contenteditable="true">
                    <a>{{student.accountname}}</a>
                 </td>
                 <td contenteditable="true"  class ='phone'>
                    {{student.phone}}   
                 </td><i class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>
                 <td contenteditable="true">
                    {{student.accountownername}}
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                       <button id="dropdown-btn-one" class="btn btn-xs" dropdownToggle>
                       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                       </button>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" dropdownMenu role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-btn-one">
                          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item pull-left"  (click) = 'getstudentbyid(student._id)'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editmodel">Edit</a></li>
                          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click) = 'deletestudentbyid(student._id)'>Delete</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                 </td>
              </tr>

           </tbody>
        </table>
```

can someone suggest help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to give the headers widths, and the editable table cells `word-break: break-all`:

EDIT: added width to the `TD`. Getting a different result in Chrome to FF without it.

```
th {
    width:150px;
}

td {
  width: 150px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/pejopadaju/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Sorry Scandrett,still no change

Comment: E=Thanks Scandrett,almost i am looking for that except the input box is moving when i give a long value.

Comment: What browser are you using?  It doesn't move for me in FF

Comment: i am using chrome.

Comment: I am getting some thing like this on edit http://plnkr.co/edit/4UPlh9Pn42yM3VPqYvoL?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127026/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-nlr-p).